# Sql 2012 Simplify Query Union

Tags: sql, left-join, union

I recently took a new job and I am trying to simplify some older queries left around and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get this down into two queries using union. There's got to be a way but I cant simplify more than what I have.

```
    select  (
    select avg (Employee.salary)
    from Employee left join Job_title
    on Employee.job_title = Job_title.Job_title
    where Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status='0'
    group by Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status
    ) as AverageSalary, 'Non-Exempt' as Status
    ,       (
    select MIN (Employee.salary)
    from Employee left join Job_title
    on Employee.job_title = Job_title.Job_title
    where Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status='0'
    group by Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status
    ) as MinimumSalary, 'Non-Exempt' as Status
    ,       (
    select MAX (Employee.salary)
    from Employee left join Job_title
    on Employee.job_title = Job_title.Job_title
    where Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status='0'
    group by Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status
    ) as MaximumSalary, 'Non_Exempt' as Status
 UNION
    select  (
    select avg (Employee.salary)
    from Employee left join Job_title
    on Employee.job_title = Job_title.Job_title
    where Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status='1'
    group by Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status
    ) as AverageSalary, 'Exempt' as Status
    ,       (
    select MIN (Employee.salary)
    from Employee left join Job_title
    on Employee.job_title = Job_title.Job_title
    where Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status='1'
    group by Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status
    ) as MinimumSalary, 'Exempt' as Status
    ,       (
    select MAX (Employee.salary) 
    from Employee left join Job_title
    on Employee.job_title = Job_title.Job_title
    where Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status='1'
    group by Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status
    )as MaximumSalary, 'Exempt' as Status
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or are you asking how to simplify it more? Or are you asking how to make it run faster?

Comment: I get the expected output of 6 columns and 2 rows of labeled data, I was just trying to simply this overly verbose query and got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only selecting 1 field in each of the subqueries, you don't need a "Group By".  Also, depending on the the data, you might not need to link in the Job_title Table.

If you need the Job_title table then...

```
SELECT Min(salary), Max(salary), Avg(salary), 'Non-Exempt' AS Status 
FROM   (SELECT employee.salary 
        FROM   employee 
                LEFT JOIN job_title  ON employee.job_title = job_title.job_title 
        WHERE  employee.exempt_non_exempt_status = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT Min(salary), Max(salary), Avg(salary), 'Exempt' AS Status 
FROM   (SELECT employee.salary 
        FROM   employee 
               LEFT JOIN job_title 
                      ON employee.job_title = job_title.job_title 
        WHERE  employee.exempt_non_exempt_status = '1')
```

If you don't need to link in the Job_title (since you're not using it anywhere) then...

```
SELECT Min(salary), Max(salary), Avg(salary), 'Non-Exempt' AS Status 
FROM   (SELECT employee.salary 
        FROM   employee 
        WHERE  employee.exempt_non_exempt_status = '0') 
UNION 
SELECT Min(salary), Max(salary), Avg(salary), 'Exempt' AS Status 
FROM   (SELECT employee.salary 
        FROM   employee 
        WHERE  employee.exempt_non_exempt_status = '1')
```

Comment: I was tracking the join down and couldn't see why it was even there myself I was going to start there but got hung up when I started stripping things out getting the good old "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Union'"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
select min(salary), max(salary), avg(salary), 'Non-Exempt' as otherThingy
from (
    select Employee.salary
    from Employee left join Job_title
    on Employee.job_title = Job_title.Job_title
    where Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status='0'
) thingy
UNION
select min(salary), max(salary), avg(salary), 'Exempt' as otherThingy
from (
    select Employee.salary
    from Employee left join Job_title
    on Employee.job_title = Job_title.Job_title
    where Employee.Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status='1'
) thingy
```

or to get really fancy you could do it all in one go most likely:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b437/1

```
select 
    min(salary), 
    max(salary), 
    avg(salary), 
    case when Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status = 0 
        then 'Non-Exempt' 
        else 'Exempt' 
    end as exemptStatus
from (
    select Employee.salary, Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status
    from Employee
) thingy
group by Exempt_Non_Exempt_Status
```

Comment: Excellent! That was the trick. No union error now and I got the data I once got when it was bloat ware!!!!! I love this site!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the fast response. here is the code I went with. I was able to get the same results with all the code provided and want to thank you all.

```
SELECT Min(salary) as 'Minimum Salary', Max(salary) as 'Maximum Salary',Avg(salary) as 'Average Salary', 'Non-Exempt' AS Status 
FROM   (SELECT employee.salary 
    FROM   employee 
    WHERE  employee.exempt_non_exempt_status = '0') thingy1
UNION 
SELECT Min(salary) as 'Minimum Salary', Max(salary) as 'Maximum Salary', Avg(salary) as 'Average Salary', 'Exempt' AS Status 
FROM   (SELECT employee.salary 
    FROM   employee 
    WHERE  employee.exempt_non_exempt_status = '1') thingy2
```